# Modernizr.load()/yepnope : Error when loading JQuery before JS plugins

Tags: javascript, jquery, performance, modernizr, yepnope

I'm using Modernizr to load all of my JS and CSS scripts in a specific order with callbacks functions to manage the dependences. But I meet a problem with the loading of Bootstrap witch need JQuery. I have 3 levels of loading :

1) JQuery lib

2) scripts using JQuery but not needing that the document is loaded

3) scripts using JQuery AND needing document loaded

I get the following error in Firbug :

> TypeError: l is not a function bootstrap.min.js (ligne 4)

It seems that JQuery does not have time to load before Bootstrap.

Does anybody have an idea please? (to resolve this problem or to purpose another solution to make the same thing) Thanks for your help.

The code in head :

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/modernizr-2.6.1.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">

    Modernizr.load([{
        load: 'http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.min.js',
        complete: function(){

            Modernizr.load([
                //scripts using JQuery but not needing that the document is loaded
                'bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js',
                'js/plugins/respond/respond.min.js',
                'js/plugins/jquery-ui/jquery-ui-1.8.23.custom.min.js',
                'js/plugins/easing/jquery.easing.1.3.js',
                'js/plugins/parallax/js/jquery.stellar.min.js'
            ]);

            $(function(){
                //scripts using JQuery AND needing document loaded
                Modernizr.load([
                    {
                        test : Modernizr.touch,
                        yep : 'js/plugins/toucheeffect/toucheffects.js'
                    },{
                        test : $('.camera_wrap').length,
                        yep : {
                            'js':'js/plugins/camera/camera.min.js',
                            'css':'js/plugins/camera/css/camera.css'
                        },
                        complete : {
                            'js': function(){
                                $('.camera_wrap').camera();
                                console.log("plugin loaded!");
                            }
                        }
                    }
                ]);
            });
        }
    }]);
</script>
```

[EDIT] alert(jQuery) at the beginning of the first callback function is OK so I don't understand why Bootrstarp don't run correctly...